# `property.whitespace` notation in multimatch Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch query which looks like the following:

```
"multi_match": {
    "query": "queried expression",
    "fields": [
        "property1.whitespace^100.0",
        "property2.whitespace^50.0"
   ],
// ...
```

I've found that the caret operator means *boosting*.

But I can't find neither in the docs nor in Google what's the purpose of the `property.whitespace` operation. Could you show me some documentation, please?

Comment: `property1.whitespace` and `property2.whitespace` are field names on which the `multi_match` query is run.

Comment: Nope, `property1` and `property2` seems to be simple strings in Kibana.

Comment: Actually, I think that you should have a look at your mapping. Most probably, `property1` and `property2` are simple string fields, but with a sub-field named `whitespace` (probably analyzed differently than the parent field)